# Reducing kinect FPS without timers

Tags: c#, kinect, frame-rate

I'm using an Xbox Kinect and I can't find a way to reduce the FPS. I don't want to use timers or the simple way ignoring some frames like

```
if(countFPS%2 == 0){ 
    //store frames
}
```

I want to reduce CPU time to achieve better performance... Is it possible to do this in C#? Any other ideas?

Comment: There are several data streams which comes as output of Kinect: they are color, depth and skeleton. Which of these do you want to reduce in terms of FPS?

Comment: I am interested in skeleton :)

Comment: Perhaps the [Thread.Sleep Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx9) can be a good solution